# Página maestra Primefaces

Tags: netbeans, jsf, jsp, primefaces

Estoy haciendo un portal web con primefaces, y lo que necesito es crear una pagina maestra, donde tenga un menu al lado izquierdo que cada vez que presione una opcion me cargue el contenido de otro xhtml en el centro.

Lo hice con un tabView, y dentro de este un include con el src al otro xhtml y funciona, pero me carga de golpe todos los xhtml que tengo invocados, y se me pierden funcionalidades.

Supongo que debe haber una forma más elegante.

Acá pongo el código:

FrmPrincipal.xhtml

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>FrmPrincipal</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Aqui va logo
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Aqui va info
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="242" header="Servicios" collapsible="false">
                <p:menu>
                    <p:submenu label="Vehiculo">
                        <p:menuitem value="Consulta Vehiculo" url="faces/FrmConsultaVehiculo.xhtml" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Consulta Comparendo" url="faces/FrmConsultaComparendo.xhtml" />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                Aca Necesito que se muestre
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

FrmConsultaComparendo.xhtml



    
        FrmConsultaComparendo

```
    <h:form id="formulariocomparendo">
        <p:panel id="panelcomparendo" header="Comparendo">

            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Placa" id="placa" value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.placax}" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{clsConsultaComparendo.MtdConsultarComparendo}" update="panelcomparendo" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Consulta" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:separator/>

            <p:dataTable id="tabla1" var="comparendo" value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.listaComparendos}">
                <p:column headerText="Numero Comparendo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.NUMEROCOMPARENDO}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Fecha Comparendo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.FECHA}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Tipo Documento">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.TIPODOC}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Identificacion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.IDENTIFICACION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Placa">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.PLACA}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Estado">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.ESTADO}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Codigo Infraccion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.CODINFRACCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Direccion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.DIRECCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Ciudad" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.NOMBRECIUDAD}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Descripcion" visible="false" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.DESCRIPCIONINFRACCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton update=":formulariocomparendo:comparendoDetalle" oncomplete="PF('comparendoDialogo').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Detalle">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{comparendo}" target="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Detalles Comparendo" widgetVar="comparendoDialogo" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="comparendoDetalle" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos}" columnClasses="label,value">

                        <h:outputText value="Infraccion:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos.CODINFRACCION}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Descripcion:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos.DESCRIPCIONINFRACCION}" />

                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel id="panelexportar" header="Exportar Información Comparendo">  
            <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">  
                <p:graphicImage value="imagenes/pdf.png"/>  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{clsExportarComparendo.exportarPersonalizado}" />  
                <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="tabla1" fileName="reportecomparendo" datasetPadding="4"/>
            </p:commandLink>

            <p:spacer width="20"/>  

            <p:commandLink id="xls" ajax="false">  
                <p:graphicImage value="imagenes/xsl.png"/>  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{clsExportarComparendo.exportarPersonalizado}" />  
                <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target="tabla1" fileName="reportecomparendo" datasetPadding="4"/>
            </p:commandLink>  
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Comment: Añade el código del xhtml y de los controladores que tengas hecho

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas posibles de hacer esto, por lo que puedo intuir en tu caso lo mas recomendable es cargar otra página via GET

Para ello te aconsejaría utilizar templates de JSF que te van a facilitar mucho esta tarea

primero creas el archivo
/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>FrmPrincipal</title>
         </f:facet>
        </h:head>

       <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Aqui va logo
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Aqui va info
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="242" header="Servicios" collapsible="false">
                <p:menu>
                    <p:submenu label="Vehiculo">
                        <p:menuitem value="Consulta Vehiculo" url="faces/FrmConsultaVehiculo.xhtml" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Consulta Comparendo" url="faces/FrmConsultaComparendo.xhtml" />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <ui:insert name="content">

                    </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
 </html>
```

Fijate en que hemos creado una posición llamada content justo aqui

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <ui:insert name="content">

        </ui:insert>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Después en el 
FrmConsultaComparendo.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="formulariocomparendo">
        <p:panel id="panelcomparendo" header="Comparendo">

            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Placa" id="placa" value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.placax}" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{clsConsultaComparendo.MtdConsultarComparendo}" update="panelcomparendo" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Consulta" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:separator/>

            <p:dataTable id="tabla1" var="comparendo" value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.listaComparendos}">
                <p:column headerText="Numero Comparendo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.NUMEROCOMPARENDO}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Fecha Comparendo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.FECHA}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Tipo Documento">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.TIPODOC}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Identificacion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.IDENTIFICACION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Placa">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.PLACA}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Estado">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.ESTADO}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Codigo Infraccion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.CODINFRACCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Direccion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.DIRECCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Ciudad" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.NOMBRECIUDAD}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Descripcion" visible="false" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{comparendo.DESCRIPCIONINFRACCION}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton update=":formulariocomparendo:comparendoDetalle" oncomplete="PF('comparendoDialogo').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Detalle">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{comparendo}" target="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Detalles Comparendo" widgetVar="comparendoDialogo" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="comparendoDetalle" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos}" columnClasses="label,value">

                        <h:outputText value="Infraccion:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos.CODINFRACCION}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Descripcion:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{clsConsultaComparendo.seleccionComparendos.DESCRIPCIONINFRACCION}" />

                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel id="panelexportar" header="Exportar Información Comparendo">  
            <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">  
                <p:graphicImage value="imagenes/pdf.png"/>  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{clsExportarComparendo.exportarPersonalizado}" />  
                <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="tabla1" fileName="reportecomparendo" datasetPadding="4"/>
            </p:commandLink>

            <p:spacer width="20"/>  

            <p:commandLink id="xls" ajax="false">  
                <p:graphicImage value="imagenes/xsl.png"/>  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{clsExportarComparendo.exportarPersonalizado}" />  
                <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target="tabla1" fileName="reportecomparendo" datasetPadding="4"/>
            </p:commandLink>  
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Con esto al navegar  comparendo.xhtml define la posicion content y el resto lo hereda del template definido aquí:

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
```

Espero que te ayude.
Un saludo